# iText throws error on deleting a closed file

Tags: java, itext

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PDFSplitter {
    private static final String INPUT_FILE = "C:\\test.pdf";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader=new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
        pdfDocument.close();    
        Files.delete(Paths.get(INPUT_FILE));
    }

}
```

It throws that the source file is being used by another process so it can't be deleted!!!

Comment: Assuming that `PdfDocument.close` hands the close request through to `PdfReader` and that to whatever underlying file system access it uses... you could still run into file system issues where the file system just doesn't catch up quickly enough. A `sleep` could help, maybe in combination with retrying a few times, but this is ugly. More likely though: do you have that file open in another program by chance?

Comment: No. The file is only for this purpose

Comment: Base on your comment I understand that PdfDocument.close is not synchronous.

Comment: And I do not think that the reason is that "the file system just doesn't catch up quickly enough". I add
`File srcFile=new File(INPUT_FILE);
  while(!srcFile.delete()) {
   
  }`
and nothing happens.

Comment: It seems that iText has the problem. Even if the file is closed in the code it seems to keep it open forever. I will switch to another library because it seems very unreliable

Comment: Odd. That would warrant a bug report with itext. Can you add the build script or the itext version you use? I'd  like to try this... but I'm not on Windows, so may get different results. The tab `\t` in the file name doesn't change it, I guess? It still fails when you have a filename like "test.pdf"?

Comment: itext7-core, vesrion 7.0.4

Comment: Something with the combination of JRE version and itext-core version. I am trying with the combinations and have different behaviors!!!

Comment: *"itext7-core, vesrion 7.0.4"* - That's a very old version. Quite likely the underlying issue has been fixed in the meantime. Please update.